# Posted model is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure what's wrong since I'm very new with MVC. This is a shopping cart. The customer is able to review their cart and edit quantity.

On the HttpPost ViewCart method, the cart is always empty, and number of lines is zero.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ViewCart() {
    var cart = (CartViewModel)Session["Cart"];
    return View(cart);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewCart(CartViewModel cart) {
    Session["Cart"] = cart;
    return RedirectToAction("Order", "Checkout");
}
```

View:

```
@model CartViewModel
using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <h2>Your cart</h2>

    <table>
        <thead> ... </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Lines) {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Article.Description)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Checkout">
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CartViewModel {
    public List<Line> Lines { get; set; }

    public CartViewModel() {
        Lines = new List<Line>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls - you need to use a `for` loop (inspect the html before and after to understand the difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the view to use indexes:

```
@model CartViewModel
using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <h2>Your cart</h2>

    <table>
        <thead> ... </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Lines.Count; i++) {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Lines[i].Article.Description) @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Lines[i].Article.Id)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Lines[i].Quantity)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Checkout">
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. You even foresaw that I need a hiddenfield for ID.